# Edit node after submission on comparing already submitted data in node creation in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nodes, drupal-views

Actually i have created one page for registration in the event.

But some how a person is submitting the form mistakenly filled the data (so he/she has to correct those data)

So person need access to edit after filling the search field (validating the data such as (1)Registration ID, (2) Date of Birth and (3) Mobile number ....

if all three details are correct. a submitter will get access to the node edit. But a person does not require to register for doing this.

Kindly help me to create this type facility for my website.

Thanking you.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Are you talking about views exposed filters? Also, there is a community of Drupal experts here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, i need edit rights to anonymous user for change node he has submitted.

Comment: After submitting the node,  if annonymous user need to change the details. he should change. but need some combination to unlock the node he has submitted..... upon sucessful verification to such information, he will get access the node edit form and then submit